# Hibernate: Criteria & createSQLQuery: how to get proper JSON?

Tags: java, sql, json, spring, hibernate

When I try this I get the proper JSON as a result, but it takes a lot of time:

```
        Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        List<User> users = c.list();
        List<User> specialUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (User user : users) {
            List<Perm> userPerms = user.getProfile().getPerms();

            for (Perm perm : userPerms) {
                if (perm.getId().equals(SPECIAL_ID)) {
                    specialUsers.add(user);
                }
            }
        }

        return specialUsers;
```

and the JSON is like:

```
[{"id":111,"name":"Name111"},{"id":222,"name":"Name222"}]
```

In attempt to improve performance I tried code below. In SQL app the results are OK, a few records of users:

```
        String sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name FROM app.user u inner join app.perms p where u.profile = p.profile AND p.right= :rightId";
        List<User> specialUsers= (List<User>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(sql)
                .setParameter("rightId", SPECIAL_ID)
                .list();

        return specialUsers;
```

Now the 'JSON' however looks like this:

```
[[111,"Name111"],[222,"Name222"]]
```

I tried several things, like `select *`, `criteria.add(Restrictions...)` but to no effect. What I noticed is that in the first case `specialUsers.toString` returns proper data, in the second case it returns meaningless Strings like `Ljava.lang.Object;@23e1469f`.

Any hints how to solve this?

Comment: you are getting `Ljava.lang.Object;@23e1469f` as you try to convert object to string. Btw, where are you expecting this json, in client side?

Comment: Yes. I use angularJS. As for this converting objects to String I wanted to point out that data acquired in the first case - when I just get a few thousand users and then filter them - is "string-convertible", because I am getting "full" User objects. In the second case I only query for two fields as "select *" is impossible...

Comment: can you try writing a constructor having those two fields you selected in your query and update what you get then?

Comment: First I got an error 'No default constructo for entity', so I added also the non-argument constructor. Then nothing changed, JSON still is not pretty.

Comment: Can you please share your related code base? from controller to dao layer? Btw, there is another simple solution: directly convert your result list to json using jackson mapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in this way, may not be perfect:

```
        // get ids of all special users
        String sql = "SELECT u.id FROM app.user u inner join app.perms p where u.profile = p.profile AND p.right= :rightId";
        List<Integer> intIds = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(sql)
                .setParameter("rightId", SPECIAL_ID)
                .list();

        // convert to long values
        List<Long> longIds = intIds.stream()
                .mapToLong(Integer::longValue)
                .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

        // get all special users
        Criteria c = sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(User.class)
                .add(Restrictions.in("id", longIds));

        List<User> specialUsers = c.list();
        return specialUsers;
    }
```